# Google AdMob iPhone5C iPhone5S 64bit Simulator issue

Tags: ios, 64-bit, admob

During compilation of a project with target: iPhone Retina (4-inch 64bit) I have a problem with library:

> OBJC_CLASS_$_GADBannerView

and I've thie error:

> ld: warning: ignoring file
>   /Users/myName/Downloads/GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS-6.5.1/libGoogleAdMobAds.a,
>   missing required architecture x86_64 in file
>   /Users/myName/Downloads/GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS-6.5.1/libGoogleAdMobAds.a
>   (3 slices)

Seems that Google haven't implemented the 64bit version of his AdMob api?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a library is compiled for arm64 by running the "file" command in a terminal. Here is an example...

> >>> file /path/to/lib/libGoogleAdMobAds.a
>
> > libGoogleAdMobAds.a: Mach-O universal binary with 5 architectures
> >
> > libGoogleAdMobAds.a (for architecture armv7):    current ar archive random library
> >
> > libGoogleAdMobAds.a (for architecture armv7s):   current ar archive random library
> >
> > libGoogleAdMobAds.a (for architecture cputype (16777228) cpusubtype (0)):    current ar archive random library
> >
> > libGoogleAdMobAds.a (for architecture i386):  current ar archive random library
> >
> > libGoogleAdMobAds.a (for architecture x86_64):    current ar archive random library

The latest version of libGoogleAdMobAds.a still doesn't have an arm64 slice, so you cannot (yet) compile your code for 64-bit.

As Blasco73 points out, to exclude 64-bit you need to do the following:

> Project -> Build Settings -> Architectures and choose Standard artitectures (armv7, armv7s) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)